# Using group_by in summarize

Tags: r, summarize

Here is my df.

| Airline | Destination | delayed | ontime | Total_Arrivals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | Los Angelos | 62 | 497 | 559 |
| Alaska | Phoenix | 12 | 221 | 233 |
| Alaska | San Diego | 20 | 212 | 232 |
| Alaska | San Francisco | 102 | 503 | 605 |
| Alaska | Seatlle | 305 | 1841 | 2146 |
| AM West | Los Angelos | 117 | 694 | 811 |
| AM West | Phoenix | 415 | 4840 | 5255 |
| AM West | San Diego | 65 | 383 | 448 |
| AM West | San Francisco | 129 | 320 | 449 |
| AM West | Seatlle | 61 | 201 | 262 |

This is my desired dataframe

| Airline | delayed | ontime | Total_Arrivals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | 501 | 3274 | 3775 |
| AM West | 787 | 6438 | 7225 |

Here is my code

```
      Overview_All_Flights_test<- summarize(Airline_Arrivals_Wide
    ,group_by(Airline)
    , Airline
    , Total_Ontime_by_Airline=sum(ontime)
    , Total_Delayed_by_Airline=sum(delayed)
    , Total_Arrivals_by_Airline= sum(Total_Arrivals))
```

The group_by produces an error

Error in `summarize()`:
ℹ In argument: `group_by(Airline)`.
ℹ In row 1.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'group_by' applied to an object of class "character"
Backtrace:

1. dplyr::summarize(...)
2. dplyr::group_by(Airline)

Just wondering if the group_by cannot be used in this and what is wrong with my code in order to make the desired df.

THanks!

Comment: You need to apply `group_by` to the data frame and not as separate element.  As a single call it would be:   `summarize(group_by(Airline_Arrivals_Wide, Airline), Total_Ontime_by_Airline=sum(ontime), ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the conventional way is to call the `dplyr::group_by()` before the `dplyr::summarise()` like this:

```
df %>%
    # build groupings 
    dplyr::group_by(col_name) %>% 
    # perfrom operation per group
    dplyr::summarise(sum(to_sum_column)) %>%
    # release groupings to prevent unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup()
```

Though since [dplyr 1.1](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/dplyr-1-1-0-is-coming-soon/) you are able to reduce the code into the `dplyr::summarise()` call:

```
df %>%
    # no separated dplyr::group_by() and dplyr::ungroup() needed
    dplyr::summarise(new_col = sum(to_sum_column), .by = to_group by)
```

Comment: Thanks. is it possible to use summarize twice with the '%>%' pipe?

like 
'dplyr::summarise(sum(to_sum_column)) %>%'               
followed by another                     
'dplyr::summarise(sum(to_sum_column)) %>%'

Comment: if you want to group by more then one colume use "dplyr::group_by(col_name_1, col_name_2)  %>%" if you sequence groupings in distinct calls they just overwrite eachother (grouping of the last call will be the efectve one)... with the summarise it is similar: "dplyr::summarise(sum1 = sum(col1), sum2 = sum(dol2))" if you want the sum of sums you have to build the new grouping or release the current after the first dplyr::summarise call

Comment: thanks that worked. it also works with out the ungroup tho

Comment: @g.senorsenor yes it will work without the dplyr::ungroup() but this implies the groupings are kept as a property of the tibble (enhanced dplyr version of the data.frame), which means when further processing the data you can encounter unwanted behaviour as dplyr will work group oriented when groupins are present... depending on your use you might never notice it (or waste some time to figure out why further manipulations/calculation do not pan out as planned)